# Matching fields that don't quite match?

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I've been trying to set up simple queries for a customer to match their product sheet with the wholesaler's price catalog. The only issue that I've run into is the company formatted their items using only the SKU of the product, whereas the pricer has them listed as MFC-SKU. I've come up with a couple ways to work around this, but I'm having a hard time overall as I'm new to Access.

Does anybody know of a way that I can match two fields that have the same numbers, but don't match otherwise?

As an example, I'd like to match '3206165' from Frigidaire.f1 with 'WCI  3206165' from WeeklyPriceList.f1. They don't have the same key ID, but they do have info in f2 that match (but not specifically enough for me to base the query off of that).

Any information at all would help a whole lot as I am totally stuck here. Thank you so much!

Comment: An advanced method would be using `regex` (pattern matching). But for a simple solution a `wildcard` can be used. I'll check the documentation but it's probably `%`

Answer (score 1):

Access is quite restrictive with the `ON` clause. You cannot use any expressions there except for the equality.

Eg. in SQL Server you would write:

```
SELECT Frigidaire.Description, Frigidaire.f1, WeeklyPriceList.Price
FROM Frigidaire INNER JOIN WeeklyPriceList 
ON Frigidaire.f1 = 'WCI ' + WeeklyPriceList.f1
```

With Access you will need to use the comma-separated list of tables with the conditions in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT Frigidaire.Description, Frigidaire.f1, WeeklyPriceList.Price
FROM Frigidaire, WeeklyPriceList 
WHERE 'WCI ' & Frigidaire.f1 = WeeklyPriceList.f1
   OR 'SKR ' & Frigidaire.f1 = WeeklyPriceList.f1
```

Update: As other people suggested, you could use a `LIKE` operator, a `Mid()` function, or a `Right()` function to get your result:

```
SELECT Frigidaire.Description, Frigidaire.f1, WeeklyPriceList.Price
FROM Frigidaire, WeeklyPriceList 
WHERE Frigidaire.f1 LIKE '%' & WeeklyPriceList.f1

SELECT Frigidaire.Description, Frigidaire.f1, WeeklyPriceList.Price
FROM Frigidaire, WeeklyPriceList 
WHERE Mid(Frigidaire.f1, 4) = WeeklyPriceList.f1

SELECT Frigidaire.Description, Frigidaire.f1, WeeklyPriceList.Price
FROM Frigidaire, WeeklyPriceList 
WHERE Right(Frigidaire.f1, Len(WeeklyPriceList.f1)) = WeeklyPriceList.f1
```

Comment: The WHERE statement should be reversed:  `WHERE WeeklyPriceList.f1 = 'WCI ' & Frigidaire.f1` since the extra text is in the WeeklyPriceList field.

Comment: This works great, thank you! With the WHERE statement reversed like geeFlo said.

Comment: I meant to add more but I didn't realize hitting enter would send the comment... Is there a way, then, to add multiple possibilities for what it could be? For example, adding 'WCI  ' OR 'SKT  ' & Frigidaire.F1. It sounds like that won't be possible with what you were saying, but potentially in SQL Server that would be possible?

Comment: Check @Gustav's answer below, where he uses the LIKE.  That should work for you.  `WHERE WeeklyPriceList!f1 LIKE "'*" & Frigidaire!f1 & "'"`  Note the single quote before the * and between the quotes at the end.

Answer (score 0):

A `LIKE` and wildcard `%` will also work. It may not be as fast as the other answer but it'll account for all possibilities.

```
    SELECT Frigidaire.Description, Frigidaire.f1, WeeklyPriceList.Price
    FROM Frigidaire, WeeklyPriceList 
    WHERE Frigidaire.f1 LIKE "%WeeklyPriceList.f1"
```

Comment: I haven't been able to get this formula to work. Is there maybe something I'm missing?

Comment: It's actually the same issue as the above comment (the fields in the where need to be swapped)

Comment: SELECT Frigidaire.Description, Frigidaire.f1, WeeklyPriceList.Price FROM Frigidaire, WeeklyPriceList WHERE WeeklyPriceList.f1  LIKE "%Frigidaire.f1"

Answer (score 0):

Since you're new to Access, the easiest way is to take your table with the extra "WCI" info, and create a query that replicates that table exactly, but trim the "WCI " info from that field.  When you need to do any matching then simply reference the Query instead of the Table.  Once you get more comfortable with queries, dlookups, or SQL, then you can reference the data using the above suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use the Mid function in combination with the InStr function to isolate the digits you need which would then allow you to join the two fields.  The only issue that I think you would come across using this method would be a data type mismatch, but that's easily fixed using the Val function to convert it to a number. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Like* to create a join using *WHERE*:

```
SELECT 
    Frigidaire.Description, 
    Frigidaire.f1, 
    WeeklyPriceList.Price
FROM 
    Frigidaire, 
    WeeklyPriceList 
WHERE 
    Frigidaire.f1 LIKE "*" & [WeeklyPriceList].[f1] & "*"
```